# How do I know the page cache size of a linux process

Tags: memory-management, linux-kernel, kernel, file-mapping

Now that I can know the overall cached pages of the system by /proc/meminfo, can I further know for a specific process how many page caches does it consume? My first thought is to add up all the RSSes in smaps of a process. Any more suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Bill Randerson, Maybe you can try the below command, will get some information regarding Vm, signals and so on ... regarding a particular process.

```
cat /proc/<process_pid>/status
```

Comment: /proc/<pid>/status indeed contains quite a lot of information of a process, it contains below information of memory:


VmPeak:  1079428 kB
VmSize:  1063812 kB
VmLck:         0 kB
VmPin:         0 kB
VmHWM:     84572 kB
VmRSS:     57320 kB
VmData:   150312 kB
VmStk:      8196 kB
VmExe:        12 kB
VmLib:     68332 kB
VmPTE:       312 kB
VmSwap:    14896 kB


But I don't think anyone of them indicates page cache, right?

Comment: True, none of them indicate page cache. I guess, at present, system wide page cache information can be retrieved rather than per process. I tried commands 1) free -m before writing 10MB of data into a file 2) dd if=/dev/zero of=testfile.txt bs=1M count=10000, meanwhile executed 3) free -m. Then I could clearly see cache value been increased with 10 (in MB). But this exercise gives system wide page cache information but not per process.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/silenceshell/hcache

Usage:

```
./hcache --pid <pid>
```